# Open multiple IntelliJProjects in multiple windows

Tags: linux, intellij-idea

I'm using Linux Mint and IntelliJ (idea-IC-212.5457.46).

I can't seem to open modules in the IJ sense, projects in the Eclipse sense. I'm willing to have multiple windows. Unfortuntately, IJ says it is already open and closes one to open another. How do I get IJ to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this under `Settings` > `Appearance & Behavior` > `System Settings`.

Alternatively, bring up the Action search with `Ctrl+Shift+A`, and then type in `System Settings`.

Then for `Open Project in`, choose the radio button `New Window`

[image]